# "Какая рогастая, глазатая, ушатая корова!" — or the morphological domains of "-ст-" vs. simply "-т-"

Tags: морфология, прилагательные, semantics, суффиксы

Perhaps you've noticed this before (every non-native speaker certainly has):

> - носатый
> - волосатый
> - рогатый
> - усатый
> - хвостатый
> - полосатый

but:

> - губа**с**тый
> - морда**с**тый
> - рука**с**тый
> - уша**с**тый
> - глаза**с**тый

What is the pattern here? Is there one?

Before you hurry to reject my very premise: I am of course perfectly aware that for some, or perhaps even many, of these, both alternatives exist (e.g. *хвостастый* is not unheard of, and *Глазатый* happily thrives at least as a family name). It's just that one always wins out considerably over the other. But is there any explanation for *which* one wins *when*?

I am also aware of pairings such as *зубастый кит* vs. *зубатый кит*, which simply mean entirely different things. But again, is there a reason *why* they mean these things in that order — and not exactly the other way round?

In short: is there any rhyme and reason behind some adjectives being created using "-ст-", and others using a simple "-т-"? Or is this something like *-ic-* vs. *-ical-* in English, where [no clear pattern exists at all and everything is left entirely to chance](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/why-is-it-geometric-but-theoretical)?

Answer (score 11):

It should be quite obvious for native speaker, that *-аст-* and *-ист-* are augmentative suffixes.

Let we take for example the word *усы* (moustache). Since not everyone has it there is a common adjective *усатый*, which stands for somebody who simply has moustache. But there is also less common word *усастый*. It’s suitable for somebody who has very large (or notable for other reason) moustaches.

This makes clear the difference between *зубатый кит* & *зубастый кит*. *Зубатый кит* (toothed whale, this is a biological term) unlike other whales has teeth. *Зубастый кит* (this is an epithet) is quite toothy whale.

---

Довольно очевидно для носителя языка, что *-аст-* и *-ист-* — это увеличительные суффиксы.

Возьмем для примера слово *усы*. Поскольку не каждый их носит, широко распространено прилагательное *усатый*, означающее, что некто просто носит усы. Но есть и менее распоcтраненное слово *усастый*, подходящее для человека с большими (или примечательными по иной причине) усами.

Отсюда понятна разница между *зубатым* и *зубастым* китом. *Зубатые* киты (это термин), в отличие от остальных, просто имеют зубы. *Зубастый* же кит (это эпитет) зубаст весьма.

Comment: I’ve mentioned suffix *-ист-*. Perhaps it’s worth noting that it is certainly not about loaned *-ist* as in *футболист* but *-ист-* as in *пушистый*, *голосистый*, etc.

Comment: Actually the borrowed -ист as in футболист shares the same ultimate origin.

Answer (score 5):

I want to add to the answer by Dmitry Alexandrov some information about the origins of the suffixes. The suffix -аст-, -ист- comes from Proto-Indo-European superlative suffix -isto- while -т- comes from PIE adjectival suffix -to-. So the both retain their meanings to an extent, although the former is usually used as augmentative rather than superlative in Russian.

For instance, in PIE we have:

***a̯rtos*** - fitting

***a̯ristos*** - of the best sort

***ğra̯utos*** - heavy

***ğra̯u̯istos*** - heaviest

A derived superlative suffix one can observe in English, the -est. 
For instance, in the word *longest* (< PIE ***dlonghistos***).

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, it seems, adjectives with -т- mean that a specific feature is [noticeably] present, and -ст- means that a feature is prominent.

Obviously, носатый is an exception. Волосатый is used both ways: волосатая грудь (a breast that has [noticeable] hairs while as opposed to a breast without [noticeable] hairs) vs волосатый юноша (a young man whose hair-do is more prominent than most men have).